# Why aren't the Superset Alert Mails working, even after setting all the required configurations?

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-superset

So, I am running Superset installed on an EC2 instance. In my `config.py` file, I had only made these changes:

```
FEATURE_FLAGS = {
    "ALERT_REPORTS": True
}

EMAIL_NOTIFICATIONS = True
SMTP_HOST = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
SMTP_STARTTLS = True
SMTP_SSL = False
SMTP_USER = "***my user***"
SMTP_PORT = 25
SMTP_PASSWORD = "***my pass***"
SMTP_MAIL_FROM = "***an email ID***"

ENABLE_SCHEDULED_EMAIL_REPORTS = True

ENABLE_ALERTS = True
```

After setting these, I remembered to do `superset init` before launching the service.

Yet, after the scheduled time, the UI shows no value in the `last run column` and the logs gives the following message:

```
DEBUG:cron_descriptor.GetText:Failed to find locale en_US
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2021 10:56:51] "GET /api/v1/report/?q=(filters:!((col:type,opr:eq,value:Alert)),order_column:name,order_direction:desc,page:0,page_size:25) HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Here's a sreenshot of the UI:
[image]

As can be seen, there is nothing in the `last run column, even after the scheduled time` (I had also scheduled it to every 1 minute interval - but same results

Answer (score 2):

Alerts/reports are executed in the workers, with celery beat scheduling the jobs and celery workers executing them. You need to configure celery beat and workers to run, check out this documentation for some info on how to set this up with docker-compose: https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/alerts-reports